# Why android BluetoothSocket connect doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-studio, sockets, kotlin, bluetooth

I write two apps which use classic bluetooth, one should be client and the other should be server.
when I try to connect with BluetoothSocket.connect method, sometimes I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:923)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:935)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:536)
        at com.example.mapboxsdktest.bluetooth.client.ClientClassicBluetoothManager$ConnectThread.run(ClientClassicBluetoothManager.kt:225)
```

This is the following code inside the accept thread in the server (socketlistener is an interface for notifying components in my app that need to know about the connection status):

```
        private val mmServerSocket: BluetoothServerSocket? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
            adapter?.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(serviceName, serviceUuid)
        }

        override fun run() {
            // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned.
            var shouldLoop = true
            while (shouldLoop) {
//            while (true) {
                val socket: BluetoothSocket? = try {
                    mmServerSocket?.accept()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket's accept() method failed", e)
                    shouldLoop = false
                    null
                }
                socket?.also {
                    // socket listener is something internal for notify other components that need to know status about the connection
                    manageMyConnectedSocket(it, serviceUuid, serviceName, socketListener)
                    shouldLoop = false
                }
            }
        }
```

and this is the code inside the connect thread in the client:

```
        private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
            device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(serviceUuid)
        }

        override fun run() {
            super.run()

            mmSocket?.let { socket ->
                // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "try to connect socket")
                    socket.connect()

                    socketListener?.onSocketConnected(device, serviceUuid)

                    // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
                    // the connection in a separate thread.
                    manageMyConnectedSocket(socket, device, serviceUuid, socketListener)
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    socketListener?.onSocketError(device, serviceUuid, ex)
                    this.close()
                }
            }
        }
```

By the way - my app also uses BLE at the same time as classic bluetooth (they are used for transferring different things).

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have a similar problem